# OData Connection in Xamarin Form

Tags: xamarin, odata, xamarin.forms

My code crashes and gives the following error on simulator. It attempts to run the try block in the *GetDataFromOdataService*() method and throws an error and also issue an alert. I am using Xamarin.Form

```
using Simple.OData.Client;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

      private ODataClient mODataClient;

   protected async override void OnAppearing ()
    {
        base.OnAppearing ();
        await InitializeDataService ();
        await GetDataFromOdataService();
    }

     public async Task <bool> InitializeDataService(){

            try {
                mODataClient = new ODataClient ("http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/");

            }

            catch {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", "Connection Error", "OK", "Cancel");
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ERROR!");

            }
            return true;
        }

    public async Task<bool> GetDataFromOdataService (){

            try {

                myCustomers= await mODataClient.For("Customers").Top(10).FindEntriesAsync();

            }

            catch {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", "Connection Error", "OK", "Cancel");
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ERROR!");

            }

            return true;
        }
```

[image]

Comment: can you send on email your latest code?

Comment: Sure, I am sending it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple issues:-

In the constructor it was doing `var list = new ListView()` which constrained it locally than setting the class level scope variable.  This was therefore adjusted to `list = new ListView()`.

The other thing, was in the `GetTheData` function where the items source was being assigned as `list.ItemsSource = myList;` where it needed changing to `list.ItemsSource = Customers;`.

I've repackaged the zip file up and sent to you.  Let me know if this works for you?  You should now be able to see all your customers in the **ListView**.

Comment: @Casillas I am building Xamarin.ios app using MVVMCross framework and would like to consume OData service. Could you please give me the idea how to consume OData Service in Xamarin.iOS?